# Limit rds:DeleteDBInstance to a specified arn based on instance identifier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I'm creating an AWS IAM Policy for a script with limited privileges:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rds:DescribeDBSnapshots",
                "rds:RestoreDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot",
                "rds:StartDBInstance",
                "rds:DeleteDBInstance"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:rds:*:*:snapshot:*",
                "arn:aws:rds:*:*:subgrp:*",
                "arn:aws:rds:*:*:og:*",
                "arn:aws:rds:eu-west-1:*:db:*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "MYPUBLICIP"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The script must be able to restore a snapshot of an RDS instance with `prod` as identifier, creating a new instance with `test` as identifier.

I would like the script to only delete instances with a given identifier (`test`).

Is it possible to limit `rds:DeleteDBInstance` to a specified **arn** based on identifier without preventing `rds: RestoreDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot` from working on the `prod` identifier?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to tag your RDS database instances and control access based on the resource tags.

After tagging your database instances, you just need to update your policy and create a separate statement for DeleteDBInstance action:

```
{ 
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": "rds:DeleteDBInstance",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:rds:*:*:db:*",
  "Condition": {
     "IpAddress": {
        "aws:SourceIp": "MYPUBLICIP"
      },
      "StringEquals": {
          "aws:RequestTag/environment": [
              "test"
          ]
       }
    }
}
```

This action will only succeed if the resource contains the tag environment=test.